# I have a question about all inclusive vacation bundles, rarer scenario, question about base price

Tags: hotels, resorts

Ok, i'm sure its been asked before, but in the scenario where a person is seeing someone from another country, and wants to book a little all inclusive resort time together in her own country, how would that work, I don't want to put down two adults obviously because i dont need two plane tickets, but i don't want to get to a resort and have them be like yo you only had 1 adult written down. Do most places charge you for two guests automatically? If so, then my answer is easy, i'd simply find a great deal on my end, put down one adult, meet her at the airport or wherever then check in together, if not its no big deal either, just confused on this topic. thank you, safe travels, - Brian

Comment: Does the vacation include food, or only air and hotel?

Answer (score 1):

This is very broad as there are many ways these bundles are priced. Generally though, the price per-person is quoted with a couple and so is discounted based on shared costs of the accommodations. Trying to book such a package for one will result in being asked for a *single-supplement* at the time of purchase.

All-inclusive packages are treated as designed for the common case of couples or families travelling together, so your scenario does not fit. They best thing to do is to call the particular resort and ask if they can charge you for an *additional guest* fee if you book a package. If not, then, you will have to calculate if booking two spaces even though one flight is unused would be more advantageous than booking the travel as a separate flight plus a stay for two. It does happen for many bundles that paying for more than you use will be cheaper and I know several people who booked all-inclusive vacations only using part of the lodging.